# Python to CSV or Excel Export multible data

Tags: python, excel, csv

Hey guys i try to write data to an csv file / excel.

The problem is with Excel file i don't get it to work and with the csv it only shows me "Element div at xx.xxx.xx" etc. I wan't that line by line the product and price will be filled in to the right match. Excel prefered. Around about 1000 product which will be scrapped.

**Standard Code to test if Code work:**

```
from lxml import html
import requests


urls = ['http://whiskey.de/shop/Aktuell/']

for url in urls:
    for number in range(1, 15):
        page_url = url + str(number) if number > 1 else url
        page = requests.get(page_url)

        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        prices = tree.cssselect('div#content div.price')
        names = tree.cssselect('div#content div.title a')

        print 'Whiskey Preis: ', [price.text for price in prices]
        print 'Whiskey Names: ', [name.text for name in names]
```

**CSV Tested:**

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv



urls = ['http://whiskey.de/shop/Schottland/']

for url in urls:
    for number in range(1, 10):
        page_url = url + str(number) if number > 1 else url
        page = requests.get(page_url)

        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        prices = tree.cssselect('div#content div.price')
        names = tree.cssselect('div#content div.title a')

with open('whiskey_test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Preise', 'Namen']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Preise': prices, 'Namen': names})
```

Comment: Can you post an example on what to `prices` and `names` looks like? You probably need to access an attribute `text` or something like it to get the actual content of what you `cssselect`'ed.

Comment: http://whiskey.de/shop/Aktuell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are serveral issues here.

#### Getting the tags (div) text instead of writing just the tag elemnt itself

in your "standart code" you do this 'right' by calling .text on the selected elements.

```
print 'Whiskey Preis: ', [price.text for price in prices]
print 'Whiskey Names: ', [name.text for name in names]
```

while here

```
writer.writerow({'Preise': prices, 'Namen': names})
```

you write the tree-element itself to fuile. So instead this would be something like

```
writer.writerow({'Preise': prices.text, 'Namen': names.text})
```

however...

#### Not writing several rows

Assuming you had a datastructure that contained price/name pairs (like a list of tuples or a dictionary) you could then iterate of it writing a new line in your DictWriter like this:

```
for price, name in in productdictionary.items():
    writer.writerow({'Preis': price.text, 'Name': name.text})
```

#### Creating a proper datastructure mapping prices to names

now, I dont think we should do all the scraping work for you :) but basicly you want to use your tree to fetch corresponding pairs of price and name elements. once you got those you dump them in a dictionary or list of tuples.
Once you got that you just iterate over it to write your csv as shown above.